# Sleep in milliseconds

Tags: scripts

Im using xdotool to perform simple action like:

```
sleep $(shuf -i 10-20 -n 1)
xdotools click 1
```

but the after the sleep it excecutes the click always between .08 - .12 of a second.
Is there a way to randomize the wait between .0001 - .9999 of a second?

Comment: @PerlDuck i mean that it wait correctly between 10 and 20 seconds so when it randomized lets say to 15 seconds it will excecute the click command between 15.08 and 15.12 of a second, but i want it to excecute between 15.0001 and 15.9999 of a second

Comment: @PerlDuck ah i see, so there is no way to make the sleep command work with decimals or use an alternative command to use after the sleep command and before the click command?

Comment: @PerlDuck taking in consideration the 8ms loading and excecuting time of 'xdotool' what would be my best bet to make the click randomized between 10.008 and 19.992?

Comment: @PerlDuck i tryed putting 'sleep 0.$(((RANDOM%9)+0))' after the first sleep and although it randomizes the 0.xx part it does not randomizes 0.xxx

Comment: @PerlDuck thank you very much! this solved it +1 for you

Comment: Some of these comments seems to have been deleted. What was the final solution?